# Positive look behind in JavaScript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I've a document from which I need to extract some data. Document contain strings like these

```
Text:"How secure is my information?"
```

I need to extract text which is in double quotes after the literal `Text:`

```
How secure is my information?
```

How do I do this with regex in Javascript

Comment: That's not lookbehind (or even lookahead).

Comment: How would the regex with lookbehind look like?

Comment: @MattBall, how do you figure? One could match on one or more characters with a lookbehind for `Text:"` and a lookahead for `"`.

Comment: I suppose I can understand thinking about lookbehind as a solution for this, but it's much better suited for grouping parentheses. i.e. `/Text: "([^"]*)"/`

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Lookbehind assertions were recently finalised for JavaScript and will be in the next publication of the ECMA-262 specification. They are supported in Chrome 66 (Opera 53), but no other major browsers at the time of writing ([caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=lookbehind)).

```
var str = 'Text:"How secure is my information?"',
    reg = /(?<=Text:")[^"]+(?=")/;

str.match(reg)[0];
// -> How secure is my information?
```

Older browsers do not support lookbehind in JavaScript regular expression.  You have to use capturing parenthesis for expressions like this one instead:

```
var str = 'Text:"How secure is my information?"',
    reg = /Text:"([^"]+)"/;

str.match(reg)[1];
// -> How secure is my information?
```

This will not cover all the lookbehind assertion use cases, however.

Comment: But how do I extract all such data from a large document? Say into an array or something?

Comment: You use the /g modifier like what I had in my answer.

Comment: @Raj: you can use the `/g` modifier, as Crayon Violent said.  This is the global modifier, without it the regular expression will stop execution when it finds the first match, with it the regular expression continues until it finds all matches, returning an array with all the matches in it.

Comment: Hm. I get an undefined when I test the above code. When I console the `str.match(reg)` without index 1, it outputs `["Text:"How secure is my information?""]` thoughts?

Comment: @orangewarp: the `g` modifier needed removing for the example in my answer.

Comment: Cool. Works. Why does the **g** modifier kill the capturing parentheses? I was wondering because I can imagine a scenario where you might have multiple targets in a string. `str = 'Something <id="12345"> more things <id="qwerty>" ...'` If I wanted all id values in an array, it seems you would want to use **g** but then the capturing parentheses would be gone. What would the best way be here? `reg = /id="([^"]+)"/g;` -> ["id="12345"","id="qwerty""] -> then run a foreach with `/id="([^"]+)"/` ? Can it be done in one regex step?

Comment: @orangewarp: that's the standard behaviour for match with a global flag.  It basically repeats a call to `exec` behind the scenes, returning only the first element from the result array in each iteration.  The best solution is probably to run your own loop, calling `RegExp.prototype.exec` and parsing the result yourself, or use the [search and don't replace](http://ejohn.org/blog/search-and-dont-replace/) method (both of which are more or less the same, but the latter offers a little more convenience in some cases).

Comment: @AndyE Good to know the behind the scenes. Follow-Up: Great link. Helped simplify my code. I've included a sample for other people to learn. Thanks once again!

**[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TvNA3/)**

Comment: Only thing different to a lookbehind is, that `Text:"` is consumed by the match. If I want to replace with `"…"` p.e. I have to do `str.replace(/(Text:")([^"]+)/, "$1…")`instead of `str.replace(/Text:"([^"]+)/, "…")`.

Comment: How about the case when the lookahead string is a multichar string i.e. instead of ", it is ":Text e.g. - 
i/p - 
Text:"How secure is my information?":Text
o/p - 
How secure is my information?

Comment: ufff! wasted quite some time fiddling with _firefox 68.0.1_ :-( thanks

Comment: In 2020, [lookbehind expressions are still not supported in all browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=lookbehind), which means that they should be avoided unless you can guarantee the use of a browser that supports them.

Answer (score 27):

I just want to add something: JavaScript **doesn't** support lookbehinds like `(?<= )` or `(?<! )`.

But it **does** support lookaheads like `(?= )` or `(?! )`.

Answer (score 13):

You can just do:

```
/Text:"(.*?)"/
```

Explanation:

- `Text:"` : To be matched literally
- `.*?`    : To match anything in
  non-greedy way
- `()`     : To capture the match
- `"`      : To match a literal `"`
- `/ /`    : delimiters

Comment: How do you use this? Do you have some context?

Comment: that is the regex, you are supposed to use it with for instance .match()

Answer (score 2):

```
string.match(/Text:"([^"]*)"/g)
```

Comment: How to avoid matching Text: in the result?

Comment: string[0] will always have the full regex match. string[1] will have the captured text. If there was a 2nd capture (parenthesis) in the regex, it would be put in string[2], etc...

Comment: I think with /g flag you will only get full regex match for all matches.

Comment: The g modifier will look for everything on the page that matches, not just stop at the first match. You said you have strings (plural), so that's why I put the /g modifier there.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var str = 'Text:"How secure is my information?"';
var obj = eval('({'+str+'})')
console.log(obj.Text);
</script>
```

Comment: Modern browsers also have [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), which may be preferred over `eval`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid the regular expression all together you can do:

```
var texts = file.split('Text:"').slice(1).map(function (text) {
  return text.slice(0, text.lastIndexOf('"')); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example showing how you can approach this.

1) Given this input string:

```
const inputText = 
`Text:"How secure is my information?"someRandomTextHere
Voice:"Not very much"
Text:"How to improve this?"
Voice:"Don't use '123456' for your password"
Text:"OK just like in the "Hackers" movie."`;
```

2) Extract data in double quotes after the literal `Text:` so that the results is an array with all matches like so:

```
["How secure is my information?",
 "How to improve this?",
 "OK just like in the \"Hackers\" movie."]
```

**SOLUTION**

```
function getText(text) {
  return text
    .match(/Text:".*"/g)
    .map(item => item.match(/^Text:"(.*)"/)[1]);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(    getText(inputText)    ));
```

**RUN SNIPPET TO SEE A WORKING DEMO**

```js
const inputText = 
`Text:"How secure is my information?"someRandomTextHere
Voice:"Not very much"
Text:"How to improve this?"
Voice:"Don't use '123456' for your password"
Text:"OK just like in the "Hackers" movie."`;



function getText(text) {
  return text
    .match(/Text:".*"/g)
    .map(item => item.match(/^Text:"(.*)"/)[1]);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(    getText(inputText)    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you, like me, get here while researching a bug related to the Cloudinary gem, you may find this useful:

Cloudinary recently released version 1.16.0 of their gem. In Safari, this crashes with the error 'Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name'.

A bug report has been filed. In the meantime I reverted to **1.15.0** and the error went away.

Hope this saves someone some lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression with lookbehind

```js
regex = /(?<=.*?:).*/g
```

can be used to produce an array with all matches found in the `inputText` (from Piotr Berebecki's answer):

```
> inputText.match(regex)
[
  '"How secure is my information?"someRandomTextHere',
  '"Not very much"',
  '"How to improve this?"',
  `"Don't use '123456' for your password"`,
  '"OK just like in the "Hackers" movie."'
]
```

Each match consists of the quoted string following the first colon in a line.

In the absence of lookbehinds, a regular expression with groups can be used:

```js
regex = /(.*?:)(.*)/g
```

With this, each match consists of a complete line, with two groups: the first containing the part up to the colon and the second containing the rest.

```
> inputText.match(regex)
[
  'Text:"How secure is my information?"someRandomTextHere',
  'Voice:"Not very much"',
  'Text:"How to improve this?"',
  `Voice:"Don't use '123456' for your password"`,
  'Text:"OK just like in the "Hackers" movie."'
]
```

To see the groups, you must use the `.exec` method. The first match looks so:

```
> [...regex.exec(inputText)]
[
  'Text:"How secure is my information?"someRandomTextHere',
  'Text:',
  '"How secure is my information?"someRandomTextHere'
]
```

To loop over all matches and process only the second group of each (that is, the part after the colon from each line), use something like:

```bash
> for (var m, regex = /(.*?:)(.*)/g; m = regex.exec(inputText); ) console.log(m[2]);
"How secure is my information?"someRandomTextHere
"Not very much"
"How to improve this?"
"Don't use '123456' for your password"
"OK just like in the "Hackers" movie."
```