# Regex to capture whole word with specific beginning

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, syntax

I need to capture a number passed as appended integers to a CSS class.  My regex is pretty weak, what I'm looking to do is pretty simple.  I thought that "negative word boundary" `\B` was the flag I wanted but I guess I was wrong

```
string = "foo bar-15";
var theInteger = string.replace('/bar\-\B', ''); // expected result = 15
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a capture group as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569104/positive-look-behind-in-javascript-regular-expression):

```
var str= "foo bar-15";
var regex = /bar-(\d+)/;
var theInteger = str.match(regex) ? str.match(regex)[1] : null;
```

Then you can just do an `if (theInteger)` wherever you need to use it

Comment: The problem here is that if there are no trailing digits, `match` returns `null` and attempting to access `null[1]` will throw an error. Better to first call `match`, then check the result before going further (see my answer).

Comment: Even prettier is `theInteger = str.match(regex) ? RegExp.$1 : null`

Comment: @SeanKinsey—let's get silly. If `null` is an OK result, then `theInteger = str.match(regex) && RegExp.$1;` is prettiest (so far).

Comment: @RobG, sure I just hate misusing the && operator as a conditional operator.

Comment: Hey, Crockford says it's OK as the ["guard"](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/survey.html), so that gives me *carte blance*, doesn't it? ;-)

Comment: Thanks for thinking it through so much @JamesSwift - looks great :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var theInteger = string.match(/\d+/g).join('')
```

Comment: Nah - I want to be future-proof against other integer-based classes being introduced into the CSS.  Matching the "bar-" characters and removing them to get the integer is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
string = "foo bar-15";
var theInteger = /bar-(\d+)/.exec(string)[1]
theInteger // = 15
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the digits at the end (a kind of reverse parseInt), why not:

```
var num = 'foo bar-15'.replace(/.*\D+(\d+)$/,'$1');
```

or

```
var m = 'foo bar-15'.match(/\d+$/);
var num = m? m[0] : '';
```