# Regex to match contents of a string preceded by particular string and ended with a particular string

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I make a regex that would extract the the contents of the **first** square brackets in the following?

`Block[first_name][value]` returns the string `first_name`.

`Block[last_name][value]` returns the string `last_name`.

**What I've tried:**

This was my current regex: http://regex101.com/r/jW0hY1/1

`/(?:Block\[).*(?:\[value])/`

I figured first I'd have a non-capturing match for `Block[`. Then I would capture all the content until `][value]` began. Instead this seems to return the entire string.

Comment: Post your java code please

Comment: It's tagged javascript... but check link to regex101 to see the test

Comment: I read it as Java for some reason.  My bad

Comment: I think you mixed up non-capturing groups and [lookahead/lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (the latter is [not supported in JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569104/positive-look-behind-in-javascript-regular-expression))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the matched group from index 1.

```
(?:Block\[)([^\]]*)(?:\]\[value\])
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jW0hY1/2)

---

OR make some changes in your regex

```
(?:Block\[)(.*)(?:\]\[value])
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jW0hY1/4)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `.*` eats up as many characters as it can. Use a non greedy quantifier instead, and a capture group:

```
Block\[(.*?)\]
```

If you need to capture the value too, you can use this expression:

```
Block\[(.*?)\]\[(.*?)\]
```

EDIT: And the JS...

```
var re = /Block\[(.*?)\]\[(.*?)\]/g;
var match;
while(match = re.exec("Block[first_name][value] Block[last_name][value]")) {
    console.log("Found " + match[1] + " with value: " + match[2]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression:  ([DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fH2kI3/1))

```
(?:Block\[)(.*)(?:\]\[value])
```

Getting the content:

```
string = "Block[first_name][value]";
result = string.match((/?:Block\[)(.*)(?:\]\[value])/, g);
console.log(result[1]); //first_name
```