# Regexp search not surrounded by

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to find all occurences of % that are not within quotation characters.

Example> `"test% testing % '% hello' "` would return `["%","%"]`

Looking at another stack overflow thread this is what I found:

```
var patt = /!["'],*%,*!['"]/g

var str = "testing 123 '%' % '% ' "
var res = str.match(patt);
```

However this gives me null. Have you any tips of what I should do?

[Demo](http://www.jsexample.com/#FAHgzgxgTglgDgFwHzAATtcNGBuBDKVOPBBVAXlQHoBCAbQCIByAXQBoAqAUk/qYZZUA5tnT5CYBIUoMEAU0kwAdkNQBGAEwBmVEy5NUXXftQNRqcaigKKqSVAB0AWxIQAFgApipAJQBubDRgABMAewgAVyc5JQQHAHdYeQ9rMB9zUCpIWEQUVCA)

Comment: What is the point of such search? As far as I believe you want to simply _count_ those occurences? If so, I guess it would be easier without regex.

Comment: So either quote chars? Do you need to accommodate `"bob's shoes %"`

Comment: Are quotes always balanced? Can quotes be escaped like `\'` also?

Comment: what would be the output if the input is `foo'bar%'foo"foo%bar"%` ?

Comment: @Alex K. Yes, either quote characters, no quote chars within the quote.

Comment: @anubhava, yes, quotes are balanced. They are never escaped

Comment: ok then one of the answers below should work for you.

Comment: @Avinash Raj The output  would be ['%']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the below positive lookahead assertion based regex.

```
> var s = "test% testing % '% hello' "
> s.match(/%(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)/g)
[ '%', '%' ]
> var str = "testing %"
undefined
> str.match(/%(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)/g)
[ '%' ]
> var str1 = "testing '%'"
undefined
> str1.match(/%(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)/g)
null
```

Comment: This would capture `\"$\"`

Comment: @AlexK. he wants the `%` which are present inside the single quotes.

Comment: His example uses `["']`

Comment: This works great! Could you please provide an explanation for your answer?

Comment: @user1506145, for explanation you might use [this online tool](https://www.regex101.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var patt=  /[^"'].*?(%).*?[^'"]/g ;
var str = "testing 123 '%' % '% ' "
var res = str.match(patt);
console.dir(res[1]); // result will be in the 1st match group: res[1]
```

Here is the [link](https://www.regex101.com/r/hU6yO3/5) to the online testing.

Explanation:

- `[^"']` - any character except `"` or `'`
- `.*?` any characters (except new line) any times or zero times not greedy.

### Update

Actually you must check if **behing and ahead of `%` there are no quotes**.
But:

> [JavaScript regular expressions do not support lookbehinds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569104/positive-look-behind-in-javascript-regular-expression)

So you have no way to identify  `"` or `'` preceding `%` sign unless more restrictions are applied.

I'd suggest to do searching in php or other language (where [lookbehind](http://scraping.pro/regex-expressions/#Groups) is supported) or impose more conditions.

Comment: @matewka, do you use JS regex flavour?

Comment: Thanks, what if you have this string str = "testing %". It will not be matched.

Comment: Would match `testing % '%' ` twice

Comment: @user1506145, update answer and one new version: https://www.regex101.com/r/hU6yO3/5

Comment: @Igor Savinkin This will not be matched: http://plnkr.co/edit/1dbCZhII0ggbKp0jKxQ9?p=preview

Comment: @user1506145, yes, this is not the solution. You read my update about js regex lookahead.

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm not a big fan of regular expressions, here's my approach.
**What is important** in my answer, if there would be a *trailing* quote in the string, the other answers won't work. In other words, only my answer works in cases where there is odd number of quotes.

```
function countUnquoted(str, charToCount) {
    var i = 0,
        len = str.length,
        count = 0,
        suspects = 0,
        char,
        flag = false;

    for (; i < len; i++) {
        char = str.substr(i, 1);

        if ("'" === char) {
            flag = !flag;
            suspects = 0;
        } else if (charToCount === char && !flag) {
            count++;
        } else if (charToCount === char) {
            suspects++;
        }
    }

    //this way we can also count occurences in such situation
    //that the quotation mark has been opened but not closed till the end of string
    if (flag) {
        count += suspects;
    }

    return count;
}
```

As far as I believe, you wanted to count those percent signs, so there's no need to put them in an array.

In case you really, really need to fill this array, you can do it like that:

```
function matchUnquoted(str, charToMatch) {
  var res = [],
      i = 0,
      count = countUnquoted(str, charToMatch);

  for (; i < count; i++) {
    res.push('%');
  }

  return res;
}

matchUnquoted("test% testing % '% hello' ", "%");
```

### Trailing quote

Here's a comparison of a case when there is a trailing `'` (not closed) in the string.

```
> var s = "test% testing % '% hello' asd ' asd %"
> matchUnquoted(s, '%')
['%', '%', '%']
>
> // Avinash Raj's answer
> s.match(/%(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)/g)
['%', '%']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex: `(['"]).*?\1|(%)` and the second capture group will have all the `%` signs that are not inside single or double quotes.

Breakdown:

`(['"]).*?\1` captures a single or double quote, followed by anything (lazy) up to a matching single or double quote

`|(%)` captures a `%` **only** if it wasn't slurped up by the first part of the alternation (i.e., if it's not in quotes)