# Why are positive lookbehinds captured as part of regex matches in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

The following javascript expression yields `["myParameter=foobar", "foobar"]`.

```
'XXXXmyParameter=foobar'.match(/(?:myParameter=)([A-Za-z]+)/);
```

Why is `"myParameter=foobar"` even a match? I thought that positive lookbehinds are excluded from matches?

Is there a way to only capture the `([A-Za-z]+)` portion of my regex in javascript? I could just take the second item in the list, but is there a way to explicitly exclude `myParameter=` from matches in the regex?

Comment: That's not a lookbehind, it's a non-capturing group.

Comment: [JavaScript regular expressions do not support lookbehinds.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3569116/1960455)

Comment: No lookbehind in JS. If it did support it, would be `    /(?<=myParameter=)([A-Za-z]+)/`. JS has a deficient regex engine, should be fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(?:myParameter=)` is a non-capturing group, not a lookbehind. JavaScript does not support lookbehinds.

The first element of the result is always the complete match. The value of your capture group is the second element of the array, `"foobar"`.

If you used a capture group, i.e. `(myParameter=)`, the result would be:

```
["myParameter=foobar", "myParameter=", "foobar"]
```

So again, the first element is the complete match, every other element corresponds to a capture group.

Answer (score 2):

You are not implementing Positive Lookbehind, `(?:...)` syntax is called a non-capturing group which is used to group expressions, not capture them (usually used in alternation when you have a set of different patterns).

You can simply reference the captured group for the match result.

```
var r = 'XXXXmyParameter=foobar'.match(/myParameter=([A-Za-z]+)/)[1];
if (r)
    console.log(r); //=> "foobar"
```

**Note:** Lookbehind assertions are not supported in JavaScript ...

Answer (score 1):

The myParameter is a match because you are using a non capturing group.

The non capturing group matches the text but it cannot be backreferenced.

Non Capturing Group:

```
(?:myParameter=)
```

Positive Lookahead:

```
(?=myParameter=)
```

Negative Lookahead:

```
(?!myParameter=)
```

---

The regex you need is:

```
(?!myParameter=)[A-Za-z]+$
```

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/xC1dO7/1)

Comment: `(?!myParameter=)[A-Za-z]+` won't do what you think it will do. The engine will advance one position to make the assertion pass. So it would match "m`yParameter`"