# Splitting paragraph into sentences

Tags: javascript, python, regex

I'm using the following Python code (which I found online a while ago) to split paragraphs into sentences.

```
def splitParagraphIntoSentences(paragraph):
  import re
  sentenceEnders = re.compile(r"""
      # Split sentences on whitespace between them.
      (?:               # Group for two positive lookbehinds.
        (?<=[.!?])      # Either an end of sentence punct,
      | (?<=[.!?]['"])  # or end of sentence punct and quote.
      )                 # End group of two positive lookbehinds.
      (?<!  Mr\.   )    # Don't end sentence on "Mr."
      (?<!  Mrs\.  )    # Don't end sentence on "Mrs."
      (?<!  Jr\.   )    # Don't end sentence on "Jr."
      (?<!  Dr\.   )    # Don't end sentence on "Dr."
      (?<!  Prof\. )    # Don't end sentence on "Prof."
      (?<!  Sr\.   )    # Don't end sentence on "Sr."."
    \s+               # Split on whitespace between sentences.
    """, 
    re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE)
  sentenceList = sentenceEnders.split(paragraph)
  return sentenceList
```

I works just fine for my purpose, but now I need the exact same regex in Javascript (to make sure that the outputs are consistent) and I'm struggling to translate this Python regex into one compatible with Javascript.

Comment: bear in mind this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569104/positive-look-behind-in-javascript-regular-expression

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. Sounds like it'll be a pain to get the exact same behavior...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not regex for direct split, but kind of workaround:

```
(?!Mrs?\.|Jr\.|Dr\.|Sr\.|Prof\.)(\b\S+[.?!]["']?)\s
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nH6eH3/1)

You can replace matched fragment with for example: `$1#` (or other char not occuring in text, instead of `#`), and then split it with `#` [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/onssubo7/).
However it is not too elegant solution.

Comment: One quick follow up question: I wanted to add "St." to the list (Mr(s)., Dr., ...) because some locations like "St. Kilda" were handled incorrectly. Unfortunately, unlike with Mr(s)/Dr/... quite a few words end in "st" so adding "|St\." doesn't work. My solution of putting a space in front of "St." also does not work. Would you know a solution for that?

Comment: @chrisvdb Are you sure it does't work? I cannot reproduce you problem [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nH6eH3/2). Could you post some examples? In any case, you could use something like: `(?!\b(?:St\.|Mrs?\.|Jr\.|Dr\.|Sr\.|Prof\.))(\b\S+[.?!]["']?)\s` with `\b` - word boundary - before alternatives. It means that the for example `St.` cannot be proceded by any word character `(0-9a-zA-Z_)`

Comment: @chrisvdb Actually the `\b\S+` part should prevent, the problem you described, it would match only whole words, and nagative lookbehind can affects the same fragment

Comment: Great, that works! Thanks again! Also, I'm using this trick to the splitting: https://jsfiddle.net/onssubo7/1/. I then use these indices to get the correct parts of the string.

Comment: Here's a slight improvement, so that the expression doesn't pick up any title and doesn't pick up acronyms either. It only fails to pick the end of a sentence if the last word starts with caps, which would be true if that last word was a proper name.
`(?![A-Z]..?\.)(?![A-Z]?\.)(\b\S+[.?!]["']?)\s`