# JavaScript regex to match a character only if preceded with another character

Tags: regex

I have the following regular expression:

```
[^0-9+-]|(?<=.)[+-]
```

This regex matches either a non-digit and not `+` and `-` or `+`/`-` preceded by something. However, positive lookbehind isn't supported in JavaScript regex. How can I make it work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3569116/656243

Comment: I read each answer in [Positive look behind in JavaScript regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569104/) and there is nothing similar to the current issue. Hence, reopened and edited to relieve any ambiguity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `(?<=.)` lookbehind just makes sure the subsequent pattern is not located at the start of the string. In JS, it is easy to do with `(?!^)` [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
[^0-9+-]|(?!^)[+-]
         ^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Cq6Rnb/1) (cf. the [original regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8ILR6N/1)).