# how to skip a character regex

Tags: regex

input text :    Test1 test2 test3 / value1value2

Regex: /.*

Output: / value1value2

Expected:   value1value2

Comment: Add a capturing group `\/(.*)`? Use a lookbehind `(?<=\/).*`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [regex find all the strings preceded by = and ending in &](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141364/regex-find-all-the-strings-preceded-by-and-ending-in) Or [regex to match a character only if preceded with another character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43658083/8967612)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use some positive lookbehind like this `(?<=\/ ).*`. https://regex101.com/r/T8Cy4C/7