# Regex : Using an anchor with positive lookbehind

Tags: javascript, regex, lookbehind

Regular expressions with a positive lookbehind anchored to the start doesn't seem to work. Does anybody have an idea why?

For instance the code below returns null.

```js
const str = "foo:25"
const regex = new RegExp(/^(?<=foo:)\d+/);
console.log(regex.exec(str));
```

Edit: I know how to make it work. I'm asking *why* this particular regex doesn't match.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Positive look behind in JavaScript regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569104/positive-look-behind-in-javascript-regular-expression)

Comment: Your regex is asking if the string `foo` can be matched *before* the start of the string. This is clearly impossible and therefore only works at Milliways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with `^(?<=foo:)\d+` pattern is that `^` matches the start of the string and `(?<=foo)` lookbehind fails the match if there is no `foo` immediately to the left of the current location - and there is no text before the start of the string.

You could fix it as

```
const regex = new RegExp(/(?<=^foo:)\d+/);
```

Here, `(?<=^foo:)` lookbehind checks for `foo` at the start of the string, but tests each location in the string since `^` is no longer the part of the *consuming* pattern.

In JS, for better portability across browsers, you'd better use a capturing group rather than a positive lookbehind (and also, you may directly use the regex literal notation, no need to use `/.../` with constructor notation):

```js
var str = "foo:25"
var regex = /^foo:(\d+)/;
console.log(regex.exec(str)[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `^` should be before `foo`. Eg:

```js
const str = "foo:25"
const regex = new RegExp(/(?<=^foo:)\d+/);
console.log(regex.exec(str));
```

Comment: I have tried this . But could you explain why my Regex doesnt work.