# Positive Lookbehind not supported on javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match the following string `a2eaa37edefd4a1e9bb0d082e441cd4e`

When trying my regex in node, I'm getting `Invalid regular expression, valid group`

I have learned that not all flavors of javascript supports positive lookbehind

```js
var url = 'http://file-store.example.local/files/a2eaa37edefd4a1e9bb0d082e441cd4e+1a3e5372-8fb2-44df-82ed-5603e3a1d72c'

var regex = /(?<=files\/)(.*?)(?=\+|\-)/g;
 
console.log(url.match(regex));
```

Any ideas on how I can get same results with different regex?

Comment: The answer to your question is that the pattern `/files\/(.*?)(?=\+|\-)/` would do just fine, other than that now `files/` would appear as a prefix to your output.  To get around that, look into using capture groups, which also is a way to exclude `files/` from appearing.

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/wiktor_stribizew/vL9ujam2/, based on [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3569116/3832970).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew big + for cleaner code