# Regex works on chrome but returns invalid error on safari

Tags: javascript, html, regex

```js
text = document.getElementById("p01").innerHTML; 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = /(?<=api-)(.*)-us(.*)/.test('api-stg-usw2b');
```

```html
<h2>JavaScript Regular Expressions</h2>

<p>Search for an "e" in the next paragraph:</p>

<p id="p01">The best things in life are free!</p>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

This regex works on chrome but fails on safari… I tried to replace < with : but also it didn't work

This is the error I see: 
`SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name`

Not sure how to fix it? What is the regex cheat sheet I have to use?

Comment: Are you only interested to use `.test` on it? Then just remove the `?<=` part, so it starts with `/(api-)`. There is no need to use look behind; just capture it. BTW: all the code you have around it seems unrelated. Why is it in the question?

Comment: I have webapp doing this , to make it easy shorter and  executable I made this quickly

Answer (score 2):

This first capturing group is invalid (also doesn't work on Firefox); positive look behind `(?<=..` is not supported in the javscript flavor of regex; and its browser dependent implementation; check out this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3569116/5953610) for further reading; so try to use a more widely supported "pattern" instead of `/(?<=api-)(.*)-us(.*)/`; it definitely can be written simpler without positive look behind; I also suggest try your pattern in a online regex playground like [regexr](https://regexr.com/) or [regex101](https://regex101.com/), etc...